# estimate $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n!})$ and $\mathcal{O}(\log{n!})$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

How to estimate $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n!})$ and  $\mathcal{O}(\log{n!})$.

So for example $\sqrt{n!} = \sqrt{1}* \sqrt{2}* ....*\sqrt{n} \leq \sqrt{n}^n$ and $\sqrt{n!} \geq \sqrt{1}^n$. I can't find better bounds. So why is $5^{2n} \in \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n!})$

Comment: Surely you can find a better bound than $\sqrt1^n$ for $\sqrt{n!}$. What about $\sqrt2^{n-1}$? Also note that $\mathcal O$ isn't about strict bounds, but _eventual_ bounds.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: If you don't want to use Stirling's approximation, a simple estimate is given by $n!\geq (\frac{n}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}$ and is good enough for most uses, as far as asymptotics go.